# How to compare 2 textview value and loop the code if they are the same in Android Studio

Tags: android, windows

I'm new to programming and trying to write my first app in which show 2 numbers on top and bottom. The number on bottom will keep randomizing every second and you need to click on it when the number match with the number on top.

```
int min = 1, max = 10;
        TextView ques = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NumQues);
        Random r = new Random();
        int Rnum = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        ques.setText("" + Rnum);

        final Handler h = new Handler();
        final Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            int count = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int min = 1, max = 10;
                TextView ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NumAns);
                Random r = new Random();
                int Rnum = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
                ans.setText("" + Rnum);

                h.postDelayed(this, 1000); 
            }
        };
        h.postDelayed(run, 1000); 
    }
```

This is my layout code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/NumQues"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
        android:onClick="Compare"
        android:id="@+id/NumAns" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem that i encountered is i cannot compare the two number. I tried to use

```
`if (ques.getText().toString().equals(ans.getText().toString()))`
```

but there are an error "Cannot resolve symbol ans"

Comment: Where is this `if`? Can't see it in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

The problem is you are comparing the value, before you initialize the ans text view.

```
    int min = 1, max = 10;
    TextView ques = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NumQues);
    TextView ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NumAns);

    //add your comparing if clause after this

    Random r = new Random();
    int Rnum = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    ques.setText("" + Rnum);

    final Handler h = new Handler();
    final Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int min = 1, max = 10;

            Random r = new Random();
            int Rnum = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            ans.setText("" + Rnum);


            h.postDelayed(this, 1000); 
        }
    };
    h.postDelayed(run, 1000); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your TextView ans after the TextView ques . What you have done is not preferred way of initializing a view .